# Glass doesn't let enough light through in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, lighting, glass

I have a gas lamp that shines through the glass from the inside. In one environment it works perfectly and enough light comes through the glass (normal glass BSDF). But now I have inserted the identical gas lamp into a different environment and there almost no light comes through the glass. The render settings are identical and, as I said, it is the same lamp (I haven't changed anything). So it must be due to some general attitude. Could someone tell me what to look out for in general? I just can't figure out why it just doesn't work in one environment. Thanks!

Edit: It seems to have something to do with the scaling. If I scale the glass to 0.2, it works. In the original .blend file however, the lamp is normally scaled to 1.0 and it works there too. But if I append this lamp to another .blend file, I always have to scale it to 0.2 first in order for it to work. At environment 2, I happened to have scaled it to it, which is why it worked.

Environment 1
[image]
Environment 2
[image]
Shader
[image]

Comment: You said render settings are identical... everything like Light Paths > Max Bounces / Clamping / Caustics etc.? In which way are the environments different?

Comment: If the lamp is really lighting your scene its generally a good Idea to use a light path node and mix the glass with a transparent shader (light goes through the glass via transparent shader thus no light is "lost", from the outside you still get refraction and reflection from the glass.
Could you add some screenshots and/or the blendfile? its hard to tackle your specific problem otherwise

Comment: @bstnhnsl Maybe you should explain more about the light path mixing as a beginner might not be aware of how this works...

Comment: Yes,  working on a proper answer. Just wanted to see if he's quick with the upload of his file so I can see if this actually answeres his question

Comment: Have you used an AO node on your glass material, this can make a bit awkward? Do you have enough transparent light bounces?

Comment: @bstnhnsl I'm interested in this proper answer as well... usually I either get the refraction/reflection correct or I get enough light through. Both I don't get to work satisfactorily.

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers! Max bounces / clamping / caustics etc. are all the same in both environments. And as said: My problem is not that it basically doesn't work with the glass. It just doesn't work with the one environment, although the render settings are actually identical. The lamp from environment 1 was simply inserted into environment 2.

Comment: @bstnhnsl Unfortunately, the items are licensed, which is why I cannot upload the file. :(

Comment: @James Yes.. With 4 transparent light bounces, it works without problems in the first environment.

Comment: @Tim I already understood from the question that it's not a basical problem with the glass itself... The problem is, at first without screenshots etc. the information we had was the environments are different. That's really not much to determine the problem. It's a pity you can't upload it. Because just from the picture I can't see a plausible reason it acts differently. Are those scenes in different scales? Just clutching at a straw...

Comment: just add your blend file...then we can find out. Remove the licensed items or reproduce in another blend file.

Comment: @Chris Unfortunately in this case the whole content is licensed and when I add the lamp to a new .blend file everything works normally

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann This was a good point! It seems to have something to do with the scaling. If I scale the glass to 0.2, it works. In the original .blend file however, the lamp is normally scaled to 1.0 and it works there too. 
But if I append this lamp to another .blend file, I always have to scale it to 0.2 first in order for it to work. At environment 2, I happened to have scaled it to it, which is why it worked. Yes, I know how strange that sounds, because it doesn't work with a scale of 1.0, but with a scale of 0.2 in the other environments, but it has been in every file I've tried.

Comment: I don't think that's sounding strange. Since you can Blender set to use real world units and the strength in Watts... well, the exact explanation how the strength values (should) relate to energy per square meters etc. I have read somewhere, I guess the manual. Anyway, if you for example use a point light with 100 W in a room that's 4 x 5 m this might be bright enough, but scale everything by 10 and the light isn't that bright anymore. Even multiplying the strength by 10 to 1000 W is still darker (because the strength affects the light non-linear, maybe? Not an expert) than in the small room.

Comment: Oh hmm maybe. But in that case it seems to have more to do with the glass after all. When scaled to 0.2, the glass has almost no effect on the light. With a scale of 1.0, on the other hand, the glass absorbs all the light. If I deactivate the glass there. Is the environment very well lit. 

Comment: I have now also set the light up to 1000 times as a test, but still almost no difference. I have now simply solved it with a second light around the lamp, which also looks quite good, because unfortunately I cannot invest any more time for it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

General Answer to let more Light through Glass

Cycles isnt really great at calculating light paths through glass. But you can help it find your light sources with relatively simple node setups.

Use the `Is Shadow Ray` output of a `Light Path Node` to control the factor of a `Mix Shader Node`. We just mix the `Principled Shader` with a `Transparent Shader` (make sure, the transpareent shader is set to pure white, older versions of Blender have a light gray as default).

*Note, that my glass has a thickness.*

[image]

The glass Sphere on the left is only the principled shader, the one on the right has the node setup shown.

What is happing here?

Cycles shoots rays from the camera into the scene at random angles. The rays bounce until they hit a light source (or the max # of bounces is reached). Cycles keeps track of the bounces and which type of bounce occured. The basic bounce types are camera ray (from the camera to the first bounce), reflection ray (after a reflective bounce), transmission ray (ray goes through a transmissive object) and shadow ray.

With our node setup we basically tell Cycles "if the current ray type is a shadow ray, dont try to render the glass, use a transparent shader instead" making cycles ignore the glass and the light can pass thourhg the object (almost) without further calculation resulting in more and noise free light.

There are other types of this fake glass, depending on what your requirements for the glass are.

If you dont need refraction (most common use case is an indoor scene in architectural rendering only lit by the outside sun/sky light) you usually use something called "architectural glass", which doesnt use a glass shader at all and mixes different light paths.

Comment: Yes, _Is Shadow Ray_ is the one that works best for me, too... still not perfect maybe, but quite usable.

Comment: Not perfect, but it always depends on what you can get away with in your render when using cycles and glass

Comment: @bstnhnsl Thank you very much for your answer. But as said, it works with the lamp without any problems in the first environment. Actually, in my opinion, it can only be due to some rendering settings that are different. 

Comment: @Tim Maybe you could add screenshots of all those render settings as well? At the moment I really have no idea what it is. And maybe lamp settings, scales and dimensions of the glass and the lamps?

Comment: @Tim Hm, thats what I thought. But yeah, unless we can have a look at the actual files its just random guesswork on our end. Not really helpful for anybody

Comment: @bstnhnsl Yes, I agree with you, but in this case I am unfortunately not allowed to give anything out including the lamp, as much as I would like :( But as I just wrote above, it seems to have something to do with scaling.

Comment: @Tim I recommend marking this as the correct answer. Although scaling has affected your particular issue, this answer works as well in more cases, and marking as accepted will help others find it.